# WPF command binding not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, routed-commands

I want to do a `command binding` in my WPF project:

1) I created the following module

```
Namespace Test
    Module CustomCommands
        Public ReadOnly Export As RoutedUICommand = New RoutedUICommand(
            "Export",
            "Export",
            GetType(CustomCommands),
            New InputGestureCollection(New KeyGesture(Key.F7, ModifierKeys.Alt))
        )
    End Module
End Namespace
```

2) In my main window I created a CommandBinding:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.Export" CanExecute="ExportCommand_CanExecute" Executed="ExportCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
```

3) In a button in my main window I added the binding:

```
Button Command="CustomCommands.Export">Exit</Button>
```

My problem is at point 2 Visual Studio is telling me:
**The name "CustomCommands" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Test"**
even though my main window is part of this namespace:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
<...></...>
</Window>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I followed several advices here to switch from Debug to Release or from x86 to x64 and recompile but none of them where solving my problem.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to mm8's answer I removed `Namespace Test` from the module `CustomCommands` and did a rebuild. Now it works without error.

Comment: Your code shows the namespace is TestFullscreen, rather than just Test. Is that the problem?

Comment: Sorry this was my mistake. Both are "Test"

Comment: Then it should be `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Test"`. See my answer.

Comment: Why `Test.Test`? My Main Window is in namespace `Test`. And my custom command class is also part of `Test` as you can see in my code snippets. Is it not enough to write `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test" ` ?

Comment: When I align both namespace names, I get a new error : **CustomCommands is not  supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project"**

Comment: If you remove "Namespace Test" from your Module it's enough to write "Test". Otherwise it's not as stated in my answer. The first "Test" refers to the default namespace of your application. This is typically the same as the name of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Test` to the default namespace in the namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Test"
```

...and pass a `List(Of KeyGesture)` to the `InputGestureCollection` that you are creating in your module:

```
Namespace Test 
    Public Module CustomCommands
        Public ReadOnly Export As RoutedUICommand = New RoutedUICommand(
            "Export",
            "Export",
            GetType(CustomCommands),
            New InputGestureCollection(New List(Of KeyGesture) From {New KeyGesture(Key.F7, ModifierKeys.Alt)})
        )
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: When I align both namespace names, I get a new error : **CustomCommands is not  supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project"**